# MariaDb query for max depth in graph

Tags: mysql, graph, path, mariadb, recursive-query

I have a recursive table to indicate relation of supervision, where a person can supervise many people and get supervised by other many people.

Here a example data:

```
+--------+------------+
| person | supervises |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          3 |
|      1 |          4 |
|      3 |          5 |
|      4 |          5 |
|      5 |          8 |
|      4 |          6 |
|      4 |          7 |
|      6 |          9 |
|      7 |          9 |
|      9 |         10 |
|     10 |         11 |
|      3 |         11 |
+--------+------------+
```

Can be represented by:
[image: Relation Graph and max depht path]
Of which, colored nodes represent the path of maximum depth.

My problem is, create a MariaDb(10.4.1)/Mysql query that returns a rows containing path, in this case return rows containing the keys, like: 1, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11 or 1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 11

```
select....

+------+
| path |
+------+
|    1 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
+------+
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: oopss... its maria db 10.4.1, I think its compatible with Mysql 8+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will return all possible paths and the depth:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select person, supervises,
    concat(person, ',', supervises) as path,
    1 as depth
  from graph
  union all
  select r.person, g.supervises,
    concat(r.path, ',', g.supervises),
    r.depth + 1
  from graph g
  join rcte r on r.supervises = g.person
)
select *
from rcte
order by person, supervises
```

Result:

```
person | supervises | path          | depth
-------|------------|---------------|------
     1 |          2 | 1,2           | 1
     1 |          3 | 1,3           | 1
     1 |          4 | 1,4           | 1
     1 |          5 | 1,3,5         | 2
     1 |          5 | 1,4,5         | 2
     1 |          6 | 1,4,6         | 2
     1 |          7 | 1,4,7         | 2
     1 |          8 | 1,4,5,8       | 3
     1 |          8 | 1,3,5,8       | 3
     1 |          9 | 1,4,6,9       | 3
     1 |          9 | 1,4,7,9       | 3
     1 |         10 | 1,4,7,9,10    | 4
     1 |         10 | 1,4,6,9,10    | 4
     1 |         11 | 1,4,6,9,10,11 | 5
     1 |         11 | 1,3,11        | 2
     1 |         11 | 1,4,7,9,10,11 | 5
     3 |          5 | 3,5           | 1
     3 |          8 | 3,5,8         | 2
     3 |         11 | 3,11          | 1
     4 |          5 | 4,5           | 1
     4 |          6 | 4,6           | 1
     4 |          7 | 4,7           | 1
     4 |          8 | 4,5,8         | 2
     4 |          9 | 4,6,9         | 2
     4 |          9 | 4,7,9         | 2
     4 |         10 | 4,6,9,10      | 3
     4 |         10 | 4,7,9,10      | 3
     4 |         11 | 4,6,9,10,11   | 4
     4 |         11 | 4,7,9,10,11   | 4
     5 |          8 | 5,8           | 1
     6 |          9 | 6,9           | 1
     6 |         10 | 6,9,10        | 2
     6 |         11 | 6,9,10,11     | 3
     7 |          9 | 7,9           | 1
     7 |         10 | 7,9,10        | 2
     7 |         11 | 7,9,10,11     | 3
     9 |         10 | 9,10          | 1
     9 |         11 | 9,10,11       | 2
    10 |         11 | 10,11         | 1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8nUp1mTgfsaD3651BTMD76/0)

To get the max depth, just use

```
select max(depth) from rcte
```

Comment: Very good!!! Thanks a lot! If I want to add a "where" clausule where I put that in SQL? to start my search, like `where  person=4` then retrieve '4, 6, 9, 10, 11' ?

Comment: @JoãoCota You would do it in the first UNION part of the CTE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHfuxsBfzpoyqfspn4kXTo/0